# How to use regex with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrap a [website](http://www.elitify.com/shoes.html#/page/1)
And extract following price for the items but there are multiple prices for the same items how do i filter out price for the items correctly..

Here is the code to parse the prices of the items on page=1:

```
hxs.select("//div[@class='category-products']/ul/li//div[@class='price-box']//span[@class='price']").extract()
```

Which gives :

```
[u'<span class="price" id="old-price-8963">\n                    \u20b9 8,990                </span>',
 u'<span class="price" id="product-price-8963">\n                    \u20b9 5,990                </span>',
 u'<span class="price" id="old-price-8940">\n                    \u20b9 8,990                </span>',
 u'<span class="price" id="product-price-8940">\n                    \u20b9 5,990                </span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 7,990</span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 7,990</span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 7,990</span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 7,990</span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 7,990</span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 2,990</span>']
```

Where first two prices are for the same items....and similarly for the 2nd item...but for the rest their is only one price...can anybody suggest me a way to solve this....

Comment: Which price do you want?

Comment: either product-price/price not old price....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = [u'<span class="price" id="old-price-8963">\n                    \u20b9 8,990                </span>',
 u'<span class="price" id="product-price-8963">\n                    \u20b9 5,990                </span>',
 u'<span class="price" id="old-price-8940">\n                    \u20b9 8,990                </span>',
 u'<span class="price" id="product-price-8940">\n                    \u20b9 5,990                </span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 7,990</span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 7,990</span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 7,990</span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 7,990</span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 7,990</span>',
 u'<span class="price">\u20b9 2,990</span>']
>>> s =set()
>>> for x in l:
    import re
    if not 'old-price' in x:
        m = re.match('<span[^>]*>([^<]*)</span>', x)
        if m is None:
            print x
        s.add(m.group(1).strip())


>>> s
set([u'\u20b9 5,990', u'\u20b9 2,990', u'\u20b9 7,990'])
```

I hope you can go on with it!